# Плавный скролл с requestAnimationFrame (не якоря) vanila JS

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, native

Всем привет! Получаю в консоль постоянное обновление с ошибкой. (Пример в коде). Возможно реально использовать его без бесконечного вызова requestAnimationFrame или есть еще какое-то более лаконичное и емкое решение с оптимизацией, подскажите? Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const
    body = document.body,
    scrollWrap = document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0],
    height = scrollWrap.getBoundingClientRect().height - 1,
    speed = 0.1;

var offset = 0;

body.style.height = Math.floor(height) + "px";

function smoothScroll() {
    offset += (window.pageYOffset - offset) * speed;

    var scroll = "translateY(-" + offset + "px) translateZ(0)";
    scrollWrap.style.transform = scroll;

    callScroll = requestAnimationFrame(smoothScroll);
}

smoothScroll();
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100vw; height: 200vh">
    <span>Text</span>
    <div style="width: 10vw; height: 20vh; background-color: #000000"></div>
    <span>Text</span>
    <span>Text</span>
        <div style="width: 10vw; height: 20vh; background-color: #000000"></div>
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
<body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка связана с тем, что переменная `callScroll` не была объявлена. Чтобы не делать бесконечный вызов requestAnimationFrame, нужно создать обработчик события scroll, и в нём инициировать анимацию, которую также нужно вовремя завершить.
Условие `Math.abs(window.pageYOffset - offset) < 0.5` вполне годится для этого.

А вот callScroll нам пригодится, чтобы отменить ранее запланированный кадр при следующем событии scroll.

```js
const scrollWrap = document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0];
const speed = 0.1;

let offset = 0;
let callScroll = null;

function smoothScroll() {
  let delta = window.pageYOffset - offset;
  offset += delta * speed;

  var scroll = "translateY(-" + offset + "px)";
  scrollWrap.style.transform = scroll;

  if (Math.abs(delta) > 0.5)
    callScroll = requestAnimationFrame(smoothScroll);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if (callScroll !== null) cancelAnimationFrame(callScroll);
  smoothScroll();
});
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200vh;
}

.box {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <span>Text</span>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <span>Text</span>
  <span>Text</span>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <span>Text</span>
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

Есть более лаконичное решение без requestAnimationFrame, при помощи transition:

```js
const scrollWrap = document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0];

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  let scroll = 'translateY(-' + window.pageYOffset + 'px)';
  scrollWrap.style.transform = scroll;
});
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200vh;
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.25, 1.0);
}

.box {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <span>Text</span>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <span>Text</span>
  <span>Text</span>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <span>Text</span>
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```